# Vista detallada de un modelo condicionada al usuario en sesión

Tags: django, cuenta-usuario

Tengo una vista detallada para un modelo, en este caso el modelo es `Equipment` y tengo una vista detallada condicionada al nombre del equipamiento.

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Tag'))  # tag
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Material'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Type'))
    nominal_thickness = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=4,
        decimal_places=3,
        help_text=_('[in/mm]'),
        verbose_name=_('Nominal Thickness')
    )  # Nominal Thickness [in/mm]
    nop = models.IntegerField(_('Normal Operating Pressure'),
                              help_text=_('[psi/bar]'))  # Normal Operating Pressure [psi/bar]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'equipment_detail',
            args=[self.name]
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Equipment')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Equipments')
```

Este es el código actual del modelo. Adelante está el código de la vista:

```
class EquipmentDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'equipment_detail.html'
```

Y el sencillo enlace:

```
url(
    r'^(?P<name>[\w\-]+)/$',
    EquipmentDetailView.as_view(),
    name='equipment_detail'
),
```

Es necesario que el usuario en sesión únicamente pueda ver la vista detallada del equipo que el posee, sin poder ver los equipos de los otros usuarios.

Adicionalmente se requiere validar si el usuario es el dueño de ese equipo y en caso de que ni lo sea, mostrar la plantilla de error 403.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta original está en https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066691/783618

Compara el usuario que hace el *request* con el usuario registrado para el detalle que estás viendo y si no son iguales, lanzas la excepción.

De las alternativas que expone el usuario @Hybrid, la que me parece más interesante es la de usar un mixin en tu CBV (tropicalizada):

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class NegarUsuarioDistintoMixin(object):
    def get(self):
        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(NegarUsuarioDistintoMixin, self).get(*args, **kwargs)


class EquipmentDetailView(NegarUsuarioDistintoMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'equipment_detail.html'
```

Todas las opciones que aparecen en esa pregunta son igualmente válidas, pero esta alternativa me pareció la más elegante o *pythónica*.